# Как сделать данный javascript правильным

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с вот такой вот проблемой. Имеется скрипт отправки сообщений и скрипт загрузки файлов uploadifive. Я попробовал соединить их что бы происходило добавление фотографий вместе с отправкой сообщения.Вот что получилось ...

```
   <script>
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'auto'         : false,
        'formData'     : {'test' : 'something'},
        'queueID'      : 'queue',
        'uploadScript' : 'inment.php',
    });
    $('#addcomment').submit(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');
         msg = $('.input').val(); 
      if (msg.length > 100) 
      {
        alert("Characters must be only 1000");
      }else if (msg == ""){
        alert("Please enter a message");
      }else{
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true); /
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/inment.php",
          data: "msg=" + msg,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $('#addcomment').after(html);
            $('#listdiv .list:last').hide().slideDown('slow'); 
            $('.input').val("");
             $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
          }
        });
      }
      return false;
    });
  });   
</script>
```

Загрузка и отправка проходит, все идет как бы как и должно идти, но запрос к скрипту идет два раза и получается так что один раз добавляется сообщение, а второй раз добавляется фотография и пустой текст(добавляется поле с сообщением но оно пусто). В конце выходит так что при отправке одного сообщения получается, что ты отправляешь два. Первое сообщение с текстом, а второе сообщение с пустым текстом и фотографиями. Скажите как можно сделать так что бы запрос был один раз ?

Comment: Я не очень шарю, точнее совсем мало)
Но почему у вас $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload'); срабатывает в самом начале? Может стоит добавить beforeSend и там грузить картинку. Либо для загрузки использовать другой файл, либо просто проверять что пришло. Если файл, то делать одно действие, если нет, то другое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Моя логика мне подсказывает, что 2 запроса нужно объединить в один. Вроде не сложно:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadifive({
    'auto'              : false,
    'method'            : 'post',
    'queueID'           : 'queue',
    'uploadScript'      : 'inment.php',     
    'onUploadStart'     : function(file) {
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    },
    'onUploadComplete'  : function(file, data) {
        console.log(data);

        $('#addcomment').after(data);
        $('#listdiv .list:last').hide().slideDown('slow'); 
        $('.input').val("");
        $('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});

$('#addcomment').submit(function() {
        msg = $('.input').val();

        if (msg.length > 100) {
            alert("Characters must be only 1000");
        }
        else if (!msg){
            alert("Please enter a message");
        }
        else{
            $('#file_upload').uploadifive('settings','formData', {'msg':msg});
            $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');
        }
        return false;
});
```